# After changing kernel , kernel crash is not working

Tags: 12.04, kernel, crash, pkexec

I have changed the kernel in Ubuntu 12.04.

After this, if I gave a kernel crash the *memory configurations* are getting changed and dump file is not created.. It is getting changed from 4GB to 109MB.

I am not able to find *crashkernel* in

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

and `/sys/kernel/kexec_crash_loaded` is resetting to `0`.

How to solve it ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I took these hints from this recipe https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe

> Increase the allocation by changing crashkernel= on the grub command
>   line or in /boot/grub/grub.cfg (for grub2) or /boot/grub/menu.lst (for
>   old grub). To avoid losing the settings when running update-grub the
>   change can be made in /etc/grub.d/10_linux.

Comment: I have tried this, but it didn't work

Comment: Here ram issue is resolved, but kernel crash dump is not getting generated